# Make object from an array of key-value pairs using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, lodash

I am using Lodash to create an object from an array but the result is not what I expected. Here is the code:

```js
var _ = require('lodash');
var data = [ 
  [ 'creds', 'ZHRyYWhlZMMKDWhzYW5EaG1hZDE=' ],
  [ 'loggedIn', true ],
];
var result = _.zipObject(data);
```

Now the result is:

```
{creds,ZHRyYWhlZMMKDWhzYW5EaG1hZDE=: undefined, loggedIn,true: undefined}
```

but what I need is:

```
{'creds':'ZHRyYWhlZMMKDWhzYW5EaG1hZDE=', 'loggedIn':true}
```

Comment: You have a typo at `requre('lodash')`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using lodash's [`_.fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/#fromPairs):

```
var result = _.fromPairs(data);
```

Comment: This one is the simple one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `reduce`

```
result = data.reduce((a, b, i) => (a = i == 1 ? {
  [a[0]]: a[1]
} : a, a[b[0]] = b[1], a));
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [
  ['creds', 'ZHRyYWhlZMMKDWhzYW5EaG1hZDE='],
  ['loggedIn', true]
];

result = data.reduce((a, b, i) => (a = i == 1 ? {
  [a[0]]: a[1]
} : a, a[b[0]] = b[1], a));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close! The only difference is that [`_.zipObject`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zipObject) expects two different parameters (one for keys, one for values), instead of an array of parameters.

But you should be able to do this by using `.apply` on `_.zipObject` method:

```
_.zipObject.apply(null, data);
// Object { creds: "loggedIn", "ZHRyYWhlZMMKDWhzYW5EaG1hZDE=": true }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to get object from your array.

```js
var data = [ [ 'creds', 'ZHRyYWhlZMMKDWhzYW5EaG1hZDE=' ],[ 'loggedIn', true ] ];
var obj = data.reduce((o, [k,v]) => (o[k] = v, o), {});
console.log(obj);
```